# element not found via xpath

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

I have a button:

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-auth">Anmelden</button>
```

nightwatch **doesn't** find it these ways:

```
browser.waitForElementPresent('//button[@class="btn btn-default btn-auth"]', 5000); 
browser.waitForElementPresent('//button[contains(@class, "btn btn-default btn-auth")]', 5000); 
browser.waitForElementPresent('//button[text()="Anmelden"]', 5000); 
browser.waitForElementPresent('//button[contains(text(), "Anmelden")]', 5000);
```

but it is found this way:

```
browser.waitForElementPresent('.btn.btn-default.btn-auth');
```

Why are the 4 commands above not working? I have to checkout for `text()` because I have multiple buttons with the same class.

Comment: Is it giving any error if you are using anyone of them ?

Comment: Just `× Timed out while waiting for element <//button[contains(text(), "Anmelden")]> to be present for 5000 milliseconds.  - expected "found" but got: "not found"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find element by XPath, instead of class/id try this:

```
browser.useXpath().waitForElementPresent('//button[contains(@class,"btn-auth") and contains(text(),"Anmelden")]', 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this xpath;

`//button[.="Anmelden"]`